# Issue downloading multiple PDFs

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, pull-request

After running the following code, I am unable to open the downloaded PDF's. Even though the code ran successfully, the downloaded PDF files are damaged.

My computer's error message is

> Unable to open file. it may be damaged or in a format Preview doesn't recognize.

Why are they damaged and how do I solve this?

```
import os
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://github.com/sonhuytran/MIT8.01SC.2010F/tree/master/References/University%20Physics%20with%20Modern%20Physics%2C%2013th%20Edition%20Solutions%20Manual"

#If there is no such folder, the script will create one automatically
folder_location = r'/Users/rahelmizrahi/Desktop/ Physics_Solutions'
if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)

response = requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")     
for link in soup.select("a[href$='.pdf']"):

    filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(urljoin(url,link['href'])).content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is you are requesting the link that is within github `'blob'` when you need the the `'raw'` link:

```
'/sonhuytran/MIT8.01SC.2010F/blob/master/References/University%20Physics%20with%20Modern%20Physics%2C%2013th%20Edition%20Solutions%20Manual/A01_YOUN6656_09_ISM_FM.pdf'
```

but you want:

```
'/sonhuytran/MIT8.01SC.2010F/raw/master/References/University%20Physics%20with%20Modern%20Physics%2C%2013th%20Edition%20Solutions%20Manual/A01_YOUN6656_09_ISM_FM.pdf'
```

So just adjust that. Full code below:

```
import os
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://github.com/sonhuytran/MIT8.01SC.2010F/tree/master/References/University%20Physics%20with%20Modern%20Physics%2C%2013th%20Edition%20Solutions%20Manual"

#If there is no such folder, the script will create one automatically
folder_location = r'/Users/rahelmizrahi/Desktop/Physics_Solutions'
if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)

response = requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")     
for link in soup.select("a[href$='.pdf']"):
    pdf_link = link['href'].replace('blob','raw')
    pdf_file = requests.get('https://github.com' + pdf_link)
    filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pdf_file.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the file is not properly closed after the open/write.
Just add `f.close()` at the end of the code to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use soup.select("a[href$=.pdf]") (without the inner quotes) to get it to select the links correctly.

After that, your script works, but: what you're downloading is not a PDF, but an HTML webpage! Try visiting one of the URLs: https://github.com/sonhuytran/MIT8.01SC.2010F/blob/master/References/University%20Physics%20with%20Modern%20Physics%2C%2013th%20Edition%20Solutions%20Manual/A01_YOUN6656_09_ISM_FM.pdf

You'll be presented with a GitHub webpage, not the actual PDF. To get that, you need the "raw" GitHub URL, which you can see when you hover over the Download button: https://github.com/sonhuytran/MIT8.01SC.2010F/raw/master/References/University%20Physics%20with%20Modern%20Physics%2C%2013th%20Edition%20Solutions%20Manual/A01_YOUN6656_09_ISM_FM.pdf

So, it looks like you just have to replace `blob` with `raw` at the proper spot to make it work:

```
href = link['href']
href = href.replace('/blob/', '/raw/')
requests.get(urljoin(url,href).content)
```